# A dense subset for each of two Banach sets respectively

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, schwartz-space

Let $A$ and $B$ be Banach spaces with their own (possibly different) norms. Also, there is a non-empty subset $S \subset A \cap B$ such that $S$ is dense in $A$ and $B$ respectively.

Then, for $x \in A\cap B$, can we always extract a sequence $\{s_n\} \subset S$ such that $s_n \to x$ in $A$ and $s_n \to x$ in $B$?

This question is generalized from the situation $A = L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, $B = L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $S = \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, in which case, we can find a sequence satisfying the above conditions.

I'd appreciate it if you'd help me!

Comment: You need to have additional structure in the question so that $A \cap B$ makes sense.  Perhaps there exists a Hausdorff topological vectors space $Z$ such that $A$ and $B$ embed into $Z$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_space

Comment: Just throwing out ideas.  But if there isn't a simple proof or counterexample, maybe this will provide a difficult counterexample: http://faculty.missouri.edu/~stephen/preprints/interpolate.html

Comment: I think the construction given in Theorem 2 of that paper will provide a counter-example.  If you want, I could flesh it out more as an answer, but when I have the time.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith Thank you for your comment and the paper! Also, it'd be great too if you'd flesh it out . :)

Comment: Many years ago, I met Natan Kruglyak, who I think introduced me to this property you are asking about.  But I don't remember what he called this property.  But maybe if you did a search into his papers, he could have a simpler example.

Comment: I now have an answer that I am happy with.  Tell me what you think?

Comment: Thank you very much for making it neat! It looks good. I will read and respond to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my proposed counterexample.  It is inspired by considering the dual of the example given in Theorem 2 of [http://faculty.missouri.edu/~stephen/preprints/interpolate.html](http://faculty.missouri.edu/%7Estephen/preprints/interpolate.html).

Let
$$ Z = L^1([0,1]) \oplus L^1([0,1]) \oplus L^1([0,1]). $$
Let $A$, $B$ be subspaces of $Z$ such that the following norms are finite:
$$ {\|(f,g,h)\|}_{A} = {\|f-g\|}_\infty + {\|g\|}_1 + {\|h\|}_\infty ,$$
$$ {\|(f,g,h)\|}_{B} = {\|f-h\|}_\infty + {\|g\|}_\infty + {\|h\|}_1 .$$
Both spaces are isomorphic to $L^\infty([0,1]) \oplus L^\infty([0,1]) \oplus L^1([0,1])$, so they are Banach spaces.

We can calculate that
$$ {\|(f,g,h)\|}_{A \cap B} := \max\{{\|(f,g,h)\|}_{A},{\|(f,g,h)\|}_{B}\}\approx {\|f\|}_\infty + {\|g\|}_\infty + {\|h\|}_\infty ,$$
because
$$ {\|(f,g,h)\|}_{A \cap B} \le {\|(f,g,h)\|}_{A} + {\|(f,g,h)\|}_{B}
\le 3 ({\|f\|}_\infty + {\|g\|}_\infty + {\|h\|}_\infty) ,$$
and
\begin{align} {\|(f,g,h)\|}_{A \cap B} &\ge \tfrac12({\|(f,g,h)\|}_{A} + {\|(f,g,h)\|}_{B})
\\&\ge \tfrac14{\|f-g\|}_\infty + \tfrac14{\|f-h\|}_\infty + \tfrac12{\|g\|}_\infty + \tfrac12{\|h\|}_\infty
\\&\ge \tfrac14({\|f\|}_\infty-{\|g\|}_\infty) + \tfrac14({\|f\|}_\infty-{\|h\|}_\infty) + \tfrac12{\|g\|}_\infty + \tfrac12{\|h\|}_\infty
\\&\ge \tfrac14 ({\|f\|}_\infty + {\|g\|}_\infty + {\|h\|}_\infty) .\end{align}
Hence
$$ A \cap B = L^\infty([0,1]) \oplus L^\infty([0,1]) \oplus L^\infty([0,1]) .$$
Let
$$ S = C([0,1]) \oplus L^\infty([0,1]) \oplus L^\infty([0,1]). $$
Clearly $S$ is not dense in $A \cap B$.  We show $S$ is dense in $A$, as the argument for $S$ dense in $B$ is essentially identical.

Suppose $x = (f,g,h) \in A$ with ${\|x\|}_A \le 1$, that is,
$$ {\|(f,g,h)\|}_A = {\|f - g\|}_\infty + {\|g\|}_1 + {\|h\|}_\infty \le 1.$$
Note that $f-g\in L^\infty \subset L^1$, and $g\in L^1$, which implies $f \in L^1$.  Let $f_n \in C([0,1])$ be such that ${\|f-f_n\|}_1 \to 0$.
Set
$$ s_n = (f_n, g - f + f_n,h) .$$
Note $g - f + f_n = (g-f) + f_n \in L^\infty([0,1])$, so $s_n \in S$.
Then as $n \to \infty$,
$$ {\|x - s_n\|}_A = {\|(f-f_n, f-f_n, 0)\|}_A = {\|f-f_n\|}_1 \to 0.  $$